# Correct way to zoom UIScrollView with many images?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, gallery

Which is the correct way to zoom an image in a UIScrollView with many images?

In depth, i have a contentView (UIView) with all the UIImageView(s) as subviews.

I'm trying to return the current showed UIImageView in viewForZoomingInScrollView: but this doesn't work :-(

```
func viewForZoomingInScrollView(scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageViews[self.currentIndex]
}
```

Comment: can u put your code....?

Comment: done. which other code do you need?

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=0.5;

    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=6.0;

    self.scrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(1280, 960);

    self.scrollView.delegate=self;

}
```

Comment: tried this... doesn't work. what to do in viewForZoomingInScrollView:?

Comment: return view on which u want to zoom like return UIImageView object

Comment: that's what I done. it doesn't work well. Other views overlap the zoomed one. the code is really simple... viewForZoomingInScrollView: returns the current imageView in one line.

Also, panning results paged, i don't know where deactivate and reactivate paging...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem where images overlapped on the zoomed one.
You need to create a scrollView of sub-scrollviews which hold the imageViews. Then configure zoom on each sub-scrollviews.